# Incorrect UTC time in Calendar File for MS Outlook

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook, utc

In my application of event management, i create a calendar file which is sent with the registration confirmation email. The application is in .NET with C#. I use following code to get the time.

```
    sdate = row1.StartTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMddThhmmssZ");
    edate = row1.EndTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMddThhmmssZ");
    ...
```

and then i add it to calendar file

```
    contents.Add("DTSTART:" + sdate);
    contents.Add("DTEND:" + edate);
```

But the problem is that if my end time is 3:59 PM local time then it coverts correctly. But if it ends at 4:00 PM then end time becomes incorrect.

Can anybody guide me?

Please find below the Screens of Outlook Calendar Entry and Calendar File data.

**Correct Output**
[image]

**Incorrect Output**
[image]

Comment: I think the code is working properly.  You are forgetting that the date changes at a different time.  From you posting I guess you are on PST (Pacifc Standard time -8) where the UTC date will change at 4:00PM.

Comment: I have added further information.

Comment: The problem isn't with the code posted.  The problem is with the data in row1.  All your code is doing to taking the data from row1.  The code that put the data into row one should only get the time once.  So you should do something like this : DateTime now = Date.Now.  StartTime = now,  EndTime = now.AddHours(3);  Not StartTime = DateTime.Now; EndTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(3);  The 2nd code call DateTime.Now twice.

Comment: row1 is getting data from DB and first, i am getting the start time of the event and then i am getting the end time of the event. So are you saying that i subtract start time and end time and then calculate end time for the calendar file? I will try your suggestion and will update

Comment: The database is wrong.  Not your display method.

Comment: Why in you example the start and end dates are 2/26/2020 and the DTSTAMP is 2/23/2020?

Comment: DSTAMP is the time of creation of file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. It is such a simple one that its disappointing that I missed it.

Just to help others. I just need to put capital 'H' in the string format when converting to string. So the correct code is

```
sdate = row1.StartTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ");
edate = row1.EndTime.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ");
```